# Calculate the proportions based on groupby in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe, aggregate, aggregation

I have a dataframe as following:

```
student-gender  student-current-enrollment  student-native-country  car-owner
M   BS  Cuba    N
F   BS  Brazil  N
F   BS  US  N
M   MS  US  Y
F   MS  US  N
M   BS  Cuba    N
F   BS  Brazil  N
F   MS  US  N
F   MS  US  N
M   BS  Cuba    Y
F   BS  Brazil  N
```

I need to find out what proportion of students from each country own a car? How do I do that?

Comment: What's the expected output?

Answer (score 1):

```
print(
    df.replace({"N": 0, "Y": 1})
    .groupby("student-native-country")["car-owner"]
    .mean()
    * 100
)
```

Prints:

```
student-native-country
Brazil     0.000000
Cuba      33.333333
US        20.000000
Name: car-owner, dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `grupoby` and `agg` with a lambda function:

```py
df.groupby('student-native-country').agg(
    {'car-owner': lambda x: (x == 'Y').sum() * 100 / len(df)}
)
```

Here the result:

```sh
                        car-owner
student-native-country           
Brazil                   0.000000
Cuba                    33.333333
US                      20.000000
```

On the other hand, if you want to know the percentage considering only people owing a car:

```py
df.groupby('student-native-country').agg(
    {'car-owner': lambda x: (x == 'Y').sum() * 100 / (df['car-owner'] == 'Y').sum()}
)
```

And in this case, the result is:

```sh
                        car-owner
student-native-country           
Brazil                        0.0
Cuba                         50.0
US                           50.0
```